# DisplayAlert causing application to crash in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When ever I try to put an alert message on any page in my application, the application crashes just before displaying the alert in Xamarin.Forms.

```
async void OnAlertYesNoClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var answer = await DisplayAlert ("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");

}
```

Can somebody please suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: What platform? What kind of exception?

Comment: @asp_net  I am testing my App on an Android 4.3 device, and it shows the message "Unfortunately app has stopped."

Comment: @Abhi you were asked about EXCEPTION. do you know what is this?

Comment: And show us rest of code. This part seems ok.

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace?  Sometimes updating Xamarin.Forms might do the trick

Comment: You can get the exception in the output window while debugging.@Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check to see that it's initialized? Also check the thread that is calling DisplayAlert to make sure it's the main thread. And just to be safe, are you able to change the async void to async Task?